# Reading a text document containing python list into a python program

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, file-io, readfile

I have a text file(dummy.txt) which reads as below:

```
['abc',1,1,3,3,0,0]
['sdf',3,2,5,1,3,1]
['xyz',0,3,4,1,1,1]
```

I expect this to be in lists in python as below:

```
article1 = ['abc',1,1,3,3,0,0]
article2 = ['sdf',3,2,5,1,3,1]
article3 = ['xyz',0,3,4,1,1,1]
```

That many articles have to be created as many lines present in dummy.txt

I was trying the following things: 
Opened the file, split it by '\n' and appended it to an empty list in python, it had extra quotes and square brackets hence tried to use 'ast.literal_eval' which did not work as well.

```
my_list = []
fvt = open("dummy.txt","r")
for line in fvt.read():
    my_list.append(line.split('\n'))
    my_list = ast.literal_eval(my_list)
```

I also tried to manually remove additional quotes and extra square brackets using replace, that did not help me either. Any leads much appreciated.

Comment: is something still unclear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help.

```
import ast

myLists = []
with open(filename) as infile:
    for line in infile:                         #Iterate Each line
        myLists.append(ast.literal_eval(line))  #Convert to python object and append.
print(myLists)
```

**Output:**

```
[['abc', 1, 1, 3, 3, 0, 0], ['sdf', 3, 2, 5, 1, 3, 1], ['xyz', 0, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

`fvt.read()` will produce the entire file string, so that means `line` will contain a single character string. So this will not work very well, you also use `literal_eval(..)` with the entire list of strings, and not a single string.

You can obtain the results by iterating over the file handler, and each time call `literal_eval(..)` on a single `line`:

```
from ast import literal_eval

with open("dummy.txt","r") as f:
    my_list = [literal_eval(line) for line in f]
```

or by using `map`:

```
from ast import literal_eval

with open("dummy.txt","r") as f:
    my_list = list(map(literal_eval, f))
```

We then obtain:

```
>>> my_list
[['abc', 1, 1, 3, 3, 0, 0], ['sdf', 3, 2, 5, 1, 3, 1], ['xyz', 0, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

`ast.literal_eval` is the right approach. Note that creating a [variable number of variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables) like `article1`, `article2`, ... is not a good idea. Use a dictionary instead if your names are meaningful, a list otherwise.

As Willem mentioned in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52869723/3620003) `fvt.read()` will give you the whole file as one string. It is much easier to exploit the fact that files are *iterable* line-by-line. Keep the `for` loop, but get rid of the call to `read`.

Additionally,

```
my_list = ast.literal_eval(my_list)
```

is problematic because a) you evaluate the wrong data structure - you want to evaluate the line, *not* the list `my_list` to which you append and b) because you reassign the name `my_list`, at this point the old `my_list` is gone.

Consider the following demo. (Replace `fake_file` with the actual file you are opening.)

```
>>> from io import StringIO
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> 
>>> fake_file = StringIO('''['abc',1,1,3,3,0,0]
... ['sdf',3,2,5,1,3,1]
... ['xyz',0,3,4,1,1,1]''')
>>> result = [literal_eval(line) for line in fake_file]
>>> result
[['abc', 1, 1, 3, 3, 0, 0], ['sdf', 3, 2, 5, 1, 3, 1], ['xyz', 0, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Of course, you could also use a dictionary to hold the evaluated lines:

```
>>> result = {'article{}'.format(i):literal_eval(line) for i, line in enumerate(fake_file, 1)}
>>> result
{'article2': ['sdf', 3, 2, 5, 1, 3, 1], 'article1': ['abc', 1, 1, 3, 3, 0, 0], 'article3': ['xyz', 0, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1]}
```

where now you can issue

```
>>> result['article2']
['sdf', 3, 2, 5, 1, 3, 1]
```

... but as these names are not very meaningful, I'd just go for the list instead which you can index with `0`, `1`, `2`, ...

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I now understand this better

Answer (score 0):

When I do this:

```
import ast
x = '[ "A", 1]'
x = ast.literal_eval(x)
print(x)
```

I get:

```
 ["A", 1]
```

So, your code should be:

```
for line in fvt.read():
    my_list.append(ast.literal_eval(line))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `split` (no imports needed) (i recommend):

```
with open('dummy.txt','r') as f:
    l=[i[1:-1].strip().replace("'",'').split(',') for i in f]
```

Now:

```
print(l)
```

Is:

```
[['abc', 1, 1, 3, 3, 0, 0], ['sdf', 3, 2, 5, 1, 3, 1], ['xyz', 0, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1]]
```

As expected!!!